# C postincrement in condition

Tags: c, loops, do-while, post-increment

```
do {instructions...}
while (x--)
```

should first do the instructions, then check if `x` is not `0` and go on/or leave the loop according to result **and only after all these operations decrement** `x`.

But my compiler **decrements first**.

Who is wrong? Me or my compiler ;-)? Could You please explain me why?

Comment: I think It does the check and then decrements, then runs the instructions in the loop.

it makes sense to do it that way, since the x-- is before the instructions in the loop, but the -- has a very low precedence.

Comment: How can you tell? How is "Check value of x. Leave loop. Decrement x" noticeably different from "Check value of x. Decrement x. Leave loop."? Are you looking at the generated assembly code?

Answer (score 3):

What You are saying

> should first do the instructions, then check if 'x' is not '0' and go
>   on/or leave the loop according to result AND ONLY AFTER ALL THESE
>   OPERATIONS DECREMENT 'x'

What should be

> should first do the instructions, then check if 'x' is not '0', then
>   DECREMENT 'x' and go on/or leave the loop according to result

Answer (score 3):

Many expressions in C have a **value** and a **side-effect**.

For the expression `x--` the **value** is the value `x` had before; and the side-effect is decrementing `x`'s value.

So, if you start with `x` being 1, when the execution reaches that expression, it will yield the **value** `1` and set `x` to 0. The next time the expression is evaluated, the **value** is `0` and `x` is set to `-1`, ...

Comment: I don't particularly like nitpicking, but what's the side-effect of `x+1` or `10*34-6`?

Comment: And there are even expressions with no value: `free(ptr)` for instance. That's why I said *(Almost)*.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear, I was contesting the "almost": I would think that side-effectless expressions like `x < 10` or `y + 1` are at least as common as `x++` or `--y`, so the "almost every" probably should "many" or "some". Not that it matters much :)

Comment: @dbaupp: your suggestion improves my original answer. Thanks. Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

the flow is :

1) do instructions

2) check value of x

3.1) is x == 0? then do x-- (x becomes -1) and exit the loop

3.2) is x != 0? then do x-- and go to step 1)